# Cant send message with oneSignal, Error: String is not a subtype of type List<String>

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, onesignal

I am trying to send a text from my device using oneSignal using the token Id, My tokenId shows correctly in the firebase console However as I try to send it I get an error `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'` Please help me fix it

```
class _NewMessageState extends State<NewMessage> {
  Future<Response> sendNotification(
      List<String> tokenIdList, String contents, String heading) async {
    return await post(
      Uri.parse('https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
        "app_id":
            "385efff8-************-0fe852ac796c", //kAppId is the App Id that one get from the OneSignal When the application is registered.

        "include_player_ids":
            tokenIdList, //tokenIdList Is the List of All the Token Id to to Whom notification must be sent.

        // android_accent_color reprsent the color of the heading text in the notifiction
        "android_accent_color": "FF9976D2",

        "small_icon": "ic_stat_onesignal_default",

        "large_icon":
            "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/zPloHSmnQsix82nlj9Aj?filename=name.jpg",

        "headings": {"en": heading},

        "contents": {"en": contents},
      }),
    );
  }

  var _enterMessage = '';
  //controller for textfield to clear it
  final _controller = new TextEditingController();

  void _sendMessage() async {
    //send message
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance
        .currentUser; //gets the current logged in user gives data like userId
    final userData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get(); //get username
    //create new message
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chat').add(
      //no authentication token required
      {
        'text': _enterMessage,
        'createdAt':
            Timestamp.now(), //TimeStamp is from cloud firestore package\
        'userId': user
            .uid, //to seperate chat left and right , differentiate between sender and receiver
        'username': userData[
            'username'], //the message now fetched will already have usernmae
        'userImage': userData['image_url'], //access to url
        'tokenId': userData['tokenId'],
      }, //createdAT to sort the messages in order
    );
    _controller.clear(); //clear text field
    sendNotification(userData["tokenId"], _enterMessage,
        "Testing a message"); 
  }
}
```

The error is on  `sendNotification(userData["tokenId"], _enterMessage,` The data with the tokenId is added correctly in 'chat' collection of firebase. I just can't figure out to use onesignal `sendNotification`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple fix just removed theon `List` from on  `List<String>`

Answer (score 1):

tokenIdList is list of strings are id as number?